# Jenkins ERROR: Failed to create /usr/share/tomcat7/.m2 on Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am running Jenkins ver. 2.60.2 and it doesn't seem possible, within a Maven Job, to define a local repository not in /usr/share/tomcat7/.m2.

Here are my attempts:

1. I created a *Global Maven settings.xml* and a *Settings file* with the  Config File Management Plugin, that contains:

   ```
   <settings>
           <localRepository>/srv/maven/.m2/repository</localRepository>
           ...
   </settings>
   ```
2. I Created a new Maven Project. Tried to make the Job see that file by attempting all of the following:

a) Defining either *Settings file* or *Global settings file* (I created two identical files) within the build step:
[image]

b)  Adding a Pre-step *Provide Configuration files*, and then using the variable *MY_SETTINGS* either in the *Goals and options* or *MAVEN_OPTS*:
[image]

c) Use the *Provide Configuration files*  within the build environment (and using the *MY_SETINGS* in the same way as in the previous step.:
[image]

However, none of these seems to work. The job always fails, trying to use the default maven repository location (/usr/share(tomcat7/.m2) - which I have no idea how to re-define:

```
provisioning config files...
copy managed file [MYFILE settings] to file:/srv/webapps/jenkins/jobs/testJob/workspace@tmp/config3408982272576109420tmp
provisioning config files...
copy managed file [MYFILE settings] to file:/srv/webapps/jenkins/jobs/testJob/workspace@tmp/config2203063037747373567tmp
Parsing POMs
using global settings config with name MYFILE settings
Replacing all maven server entries not found in credentials list is true
Deleting 1 temporary files
ERROR: Failed to create /usr/share/tomcat7/.m2
Finished: FAILURE
```

Do you know how to make this work within a Maven Job type in Jenkins?

Comment: This only seems to "work" if we trick Jenkins by creating symlinks within /usr/share/tomcat7 to both .m2 and to .jenkins.

Comment: I am facing similar problem